# Accessing Chat Folder in Python Using Imaplib

Tags: python, imaplib

I am trying to access the Chat Folder using imaplib but am not able to do so. The code `mail.select("Chats")` doesn't work since "chats" is not actually a label.

How do I access the emails in the Chats folder?

Answer (score 4):

any folder you want to access by imap. it should be allowed by mail server.

e.g : for gmail, check below image for, how to set access of imap.

[image]

here, "Show in IMAP" should be checked for "Chats" folder.

then after, try below code snippets:

```
sock = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
sock.login("your Email Id", "Password")
lb_list = sock.list() # print
#search for "Chats" folder and its signature
#here, it is "[Gmail]/Chats"
sock.select("[Gmail]/Chats", True)
sock.search(None, '(ALL)')
resp, data = sock.fetch('1:*', '(RFC822)')
```

Hope, it will be helpful.

Comment: how to change the search criteria . The chat mailbox may  become very long to read.